# Magento 2 Hide or remove a ui element column

Tags: magento2, layout, uicomponent, custom-column-grid

I want to remove a column from the admin grid. This is the column:

```
<column name="ip">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true" >IP Address</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

And this is the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * @author Amasty Team
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2018 Amasty (https://www.amasty.com)
 * @package Amasty_Customform
 */
-->

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">amasty_customform_answer_listing.amasty_customform_answer_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">amasty_customform_answer_listing.amasty_customform_answer_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">amasty_customform_answer_columns</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="amasty_customform_answer_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">amasty_customform_answer_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">answer_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">answer_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">answer_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
                <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <component name="amcustomform_export_button" class="\Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">amasty_customform_answer_listing.amasty_customform_answer_listing.amasty_customform_answer_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/export</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="cvs" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">csv</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">amasty_customform/answer/ExportGridToCsv</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </component>
        <filters name="listing_filters"/>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">amasty_customform_answer_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <component name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">amasty_customform_answer_listing.amasty_customform_answer_listing.amasty_customform_answer_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </component>

        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">amasty_customform_answer_listing.amasty_customform_answer_listing.amasty_customform_answer_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">answer_id</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/edit</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="amasty_customform/answer/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">amasty_customform_answer_listing.amasty_customform_answer_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">amasty_customform_answer_listing.amasty_customform_answer_listing.amasty_customform_answer_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="amasty_customform_answer_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">amasty_customform_answer_listing.amasty_customform_answer_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>

                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">amasty_customform_answer_listing.amasty_customform_answer_listing.amasty_customform_answer_columns.actions</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">amasty_customform_answer_listing.amasty_customform_answer_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">answer_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="answer_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">ASC</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="form_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Amasty\Customform\Model\Config\Source\Form</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Code</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="store_id" class="Amasty\Customform\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store View</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created at</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="ip">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true" >IPрррррр Address</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="admin_response_status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Amasty\Customform\Model\Config\Source\Status</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Response Status</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="admin_response_email">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Email</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Amasty\Customform\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\AnswerActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">answer_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

This is where the file is located:

> /vendor/skn/magento2-module_amasty_custom-form/view/adminhtml/ui_component/amasty_customform_answer_listing.xml

Comment: I tried adding  <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item> but it didn't work

Comment: Did my answer helped ?

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to overide the Amasty , the extension does it .Just click on the **Columns** and uncheck the Ip Address

[image]

(This is from their demo)